# Getting rcrowe/twigbridge to work in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Has anyone gotten the **rcrowe/twigbridge** package to work in Laravel 5 lately? I've been trying to test it but all I'm getting is an empty page.

If I rename the file from *sample.twig* to *sample.php* it displays `{{ page_title }}` which means it's running fine. But when I put it back to *sample.twig* I only get a blank page. The app.php file already has the `'TwigBridge\ServiceProvider'` provider.

My guess is the `0.7` branch is incompatible but maybe there's a workaround for it not mentioned in the docs?

**composer.json:** Here I'm using the 0.7 branch as instructed.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "rcrowe/twigbridge": "0.7.x-dev"
},
```

**SampleController:**

```
public function sample() {
    // Init
    $page_title = 'This is a sample yo!';

    $data = compact('page_title');
    return view('sample', $data);
}
```

**sample.twig:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>{{ page_title }}</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked php error log? White page usually means there was a fatal error that was not displayed.

Comment: My log is empty. I did a fresh install of L5 and I'm still getting a blank screen and no log file was generated either.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because you have set "0.7.x-dev" instead of "0.7.*" or perhaps you have not set up correctly the app.php file or maybe you didn't run composer's installation command?

First of all, set the minimum stability to dev at the composer.json file by adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"` at the bottom of it.

Then, automatically add and install TwigBridge 0.7 by doing

`composer require rcrowe/twigbridge 0.7.*`

Ensure that you have correctly written in config/app.php in the **providers** array `'TwigBridge\ServiceProvider',` .

Check if Twig is operational, run some code (paste it at sample.twig) like

`{% for i in 0..10 %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}`

The output is:
`* 0 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10`

I created a welcome.twig and modified my WelcomeController to test out your code:

```
public function index()
{
    // Init
    $page_title = 'This is a sample yo!';

    $data = compact('page_title');
    //return view('sample', $data);
    return view('welcome', $data);
}
```

The result was as expected *(can't post a SS atm, so here's the html code)*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>This is a sample yo!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a sample yo!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, still nothing. I'm still only getting a blank page. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, like I wrote, it worked out just fine.
Try repeating all steps i mentioned...

Comment: Did you try to see if Twig works at all? What output do you see when you hit CTRL+U to see the source of the web page? If it's completely empty then twig isn't rendered on your machine, if it's not having any values (this is a sample yo!) then you have something messed up with the controllers

Comment: Totally blank. I can't imagine it to be the controller since the php version works as in my explanation. At first I thought there was a typo in the Twig Service Provider but everything is as it should be. Would it be possible for you to show me your __composer.json, routes.php,__ and __app.php__ config?

Comment: Eh, sure, 
composer: http://pastebin.com/asZRM8iZ
routes.php: not modified after the standart installation of laravel
/config/app.php: http://pastebin.com/HUXj1Ymw


make an index.twig. write in it 'hello world'
set the routes and the controller to load index.twig
heck, if you just crease a welcome.twig and put random txt in it, it should automatically work
that's how I actually got it the first time

Comment: If it all fails, delete laravel, install it freshly, do EXACTLY as i wrote in my first post or add the composer and app.php configs from me and hopefully if u write welcome.twig it will load that one, instead of the welcome.blade.php.

Comment: Thanks @BlooDev that worked fine. But even better, I thought I'd try using `"rcrowe/twigbridge": "0.7.*@dev"` again without the `"minimum-stability": "dev"` and all of a sudden it worked too. I'm happy but wut just happened here?

Comment: In the IT world, we call that "Magic" :D